# CQRS - Consuming event service

Tags: cqrs

My question is regarding the consuming event services which subscribes to the event published by commands in CQRS.

Say I have a document generation service which will generate some documents based on certain events, does the document generation service load the data from the domain via an aggregate root? If so, wouldn't the document generation service load data which may have been updated subsequently of the event being received by the generation service? How would you stop that from happening?

I guess I am assuming that the event will only pass the information received by command DTO and passing the whole domain model data to the event feels very wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You really should build your read model from your events, unless you consider your documents a part of the domain (and you would have a CreateDocumentX command)

Comment: Even in that case, you should build your read model from your events, and store references to the docs in the events. Possibly even store the docs themselves in the event store, as compressed blobs.

Comment: "Possibly even store the docs themselves in the event store, as compressed blobs." Say what???? That is just plain wrong. Store the event in the event store which should contain a unique identifier (file name) and store it in the file system. Database should contain metadata only, not blobs.

Answer (score 0):

All i can say is that when you are speaking in cqrs you should describe the issue more deeply to solve or provide help to it properly.

However from what I've read is that you can have persistent storage on your write side, but ensure that you are not reaching out of your aggregate context.
[Related issue reading-data-from-database-on-write-side-in-cqrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480997/reading-data-from-database-on-write-side-in-cqrs)